# AWS CodeArtifact Repo failed to respond when connecting with Maven

Tags: maven, aws-codeartifact

I am using Maven 3.6.3 try try connect to a CodeArtifact repository.

Based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-mvn.html) AWS documentation. I do the following:

Set up the password:

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my-domain --domain-owner XXXXXX --region us-east-1 --query authorizationToken --output text`
```

then

```
echo $CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
```

This outputs a token as expected.  I also try hard-code the token in the *settings.xml* file, but I get the same error below.

**.m2/settings.xml**

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-domain-my-repository</id>
        <username>aws</username>
        <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>my-domain-my-repository</id>
        <name>my-domain-my-repository</name>
        <url>https://my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

    <profile>
        <id>my-domain-my-repository</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>my-domain-my-repository</id>
                <url>https://my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
```

Then I execute this command to upload a file.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file          \
-DgroupId=com.travellinck.integration          \
-DartifactId=travellinck-osgi-bom       \
-Dversion=1.0                  \
-Dfile=/Users/richardmarais/IdeaProjects/deleteme/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom   \
-Dpackaging=pom                \
-DrepositoryId=my-domain-my-repository    \
-Durl=https://my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/
```

**Error**

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy-file
> (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts:
> Could not transfer artifact
> com.travellinck.integration:travellinck-osgi-bom:pom:1.0 from/to
> my-domain-my-repository
> (https://my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/):
> my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 failed to
> respond

**Question**

Why can't maven connect to the repo?

If I change the password in the settings.xml to any random characters, it gets the same error.

```
<password>ABC</password>
```

**More info**

I do the equivalent using a `curl` command, and this successfully uploads to the CodeArtifact repository.

```
curl --request PUT https://my-domain-XXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/com/travellinck/integration/travellinck-osgi-bom/1.0/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom \
     --user "aws:$CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
     --data-binary @/Users/richardmarais/.m2/repository/com/travellinck/integration/travellinck-osgi-bom/1.0/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom
```

Which shows that the `CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN` is working and can connect to the repo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of a bug in maven, details [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUifX6-q7zSfuMq1aGlhwZnA/codeartifact-push-timing-out).

I solved this by using the following in the maven command.

```
-Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon
```